# Check all QCheckBox in a QtGui.QGridLayout

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qt-designer, qcheckbox

I made a GUI in Qt Designer and I have 144 check boxes. I want to connect all of them with a QPushButton to check and uncheck all of them.

How can I do that?
They are all inside of a QGridLayout.

They are named following a "trend", so I tried to write their names in a list and call each item of the list to check, but I did not manage.

This example is more or less like what I have

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'check.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self.checkBox_2 = QtGui.QCheckBox(Form)
        self.checkBox_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_2"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox_2, 2, 0, 1, 2)
        self.checkBox = QtGui.QCheckBox(Form)
        self.checkBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.checkBox_3 = QtGui.QCheckBox(Form)
        self.checkBox_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_3"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox_3, 3, 0, 1, 2)
        self.checkBox_4 = QtGui.QCheckBox(Form)
        self.checkBox_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_4"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox_4, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        self.checkBox_5 = QtGui.QCheckBox(Form)
        self.checkBox_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_5"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox_5, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.checkBox_6 = QtGui.QCheckBox(Form)
        self.checkBox_6.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_6"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox_6, 1, 0, 1, 1)


        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))
        self.checkBox_2.setText(_translate("Form", "CheckBox", None))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("Form", "CheckBox", None))
        self.checkBox_3.setText(_translate("Form", "CheckBox", None))
        self.checkBox_4.setText(_translate("Form", "CheckBox", None))
        self.checkBox_5.setText(_translate("Form", "CheckBox", None))
        self.checkBox_6.setText(_translate("Form", "CheckBox", None))




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I want to make a button to check and uncheck all of them without having to  type ao the `connect`s

Comment: Yeah, that it!
but when I do it directly on Qt designer, it creates a line for each conection, and since I have a lot of them, the code get very long
I suppose there's a better way

Comment: I was trying here, but although the button is there and changes its state by clicking, the box do not respond to it

Comment: Thank you so much!! It worked, I was doing something stupid here :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is tedious to have to make many connections, but as you say you can create an object list with [`findChildren`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren), but first add a button to the design.

```
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        ...
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox_6, 1, 0, 1, 1)


        self.btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Check", Form)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btn, 4, 0, 1, 3)


        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
        ...
```

Then we implement the logic in another class and we use [`findChildren`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren) to obtain the `QCheckBox`:

```
class Widget(QtGui.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.checkBoxList = self.findChildren(QtGui.QCheckBox)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

    def onClicked(self):
        state = self.sender().text() == "Check"
        for btn in self.checkBoxList:
            btn.setChecked(state)

        self.sender().setText("Uncheck" if state else "Check")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = Widget()
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```